# SQL - understanding 'JOIN' syntax, order

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, ms-access-2010

One part of my assignment is to convert access SQL to Oracle SQL.
I ran the query in MS access, here's the relationship table, query SQL, and the query result:
[image: Query Design]

[image: Query result]

**ACCESS QUERY SQL**

```
SELECT PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE, PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME, BOOK.TITLE, BOOK.TYPE, INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM, BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME
FROM PUBLISHER INNER JOIN (BRANCH INNER JOIN (BOOK INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE) ON BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM) ON PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE = BOOK.PUBLISHER_CODE
WHERE (((BOOK.TYPE)='FIC') AND ((BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME)='Henry on the Hill'))
ORDER BY PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME;
```

Thinking that the MS SQL might work in oracle, I tried it:

```
SQL> SELECT PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE, PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME, BOOK.TITLE, BOOK.TYPE, INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM, BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME
  2  FROM PUBLISHER INNER JOIN (BRANCH INNER JOIN (BOOK INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE) ON BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM) ON PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE = BOOK.PUBLISHER_CODE
  3  WHERE (((BOOK.TYPE)='FIC') AND ((BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME)='Henry on the Hill'))
  4  ORDER BY PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME;

no rows selected
```

Obviously that didnt work.
So, I kinda did a cut/paste/edit thing into my oracle 11g. Here's what I got:

```
SQL> SELECT PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE, PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME, BOOK.TITLE, BOOK.TYPE,
  2   INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM, BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME
  3  FROM PUBLISHER
  4   inner join BOOK  ON PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE = BOOK.PUBLISHER_CODE
  5  inner join INVENTORY on INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM = BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM
  6  inner join BRANCH on INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM = BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM
  7   where BOOK.BOOK_TYPE = 'FIC'
  8   and BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME = 'Henry on the Hill';
inner join INVENTORY on INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM = BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM
                                               *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00904: "BRANCH"."BRANCH_NUM": invalid identifier
```

so why am I getting this:
   ERROR at line 5:
    ORA-00904: "BRANCH"."BRANCH_NUM": invalid identifier

Does order for joins affect anything?
I did go sequentially from table to table, as you can see.

does syntax order matter? EX:

inner join BRANCH on INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM = BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM
*or*
inner join BRANCH on BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM

Does that matter?

are the joins in the Oracle SQL formatted properly, in the correct order?

If so, why won't it run?

---

Side note, this is an online class, and while the instructor is quite attentive, I have learned so much here from reading others posts, and asking my own questions. Thank You everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query joined INVENTORY like this:

```
inner join INVENTORY ON BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE
```

Try this one:

```
select PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE, PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME, BOOK.TITLE, BOOK.TYPE, INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM, BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME
from PUBLISHER
inner join BOOK on PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE = BOOK.PUBLISHER_CODE
inner join INVENTORY on BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE
inner join BRANCH on BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM
where BOOK.TYPE = 'FIC'
    and BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME = 'Henry on the Hill'
order by PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME;
```

Comment: I still get  'No Rows Selected', which doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: If you provide some sample data and schema I can help you further. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) makes this easy.

Answer (score 2):

Order of joins matters, for example [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586681/232279). You can't access table aliases not introduced before condition, e.g. you can't access `BRANCH` at line 5 because it introduced only in the next join.

Code from `MS Access` introduces a lot of brackets to restrict join order.  Just apply formatting to it and look on the result:

```
SELECT
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE,
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME,
  BOOK.TITLE,
  BOOK.TYPE,
  INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM,
  BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME
FROM
  PUBLISHER
  INNER JOIN (
    BRANCH INNER JOIN (
      BOOK INNER JOIN INVENTORY
        ON BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE
      )
      ON BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM
    )
    ON PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE = BOOK.PUBLISHER_CODE
WHERE
  (
    (
      (BOOK.TYPE)='FIC'
    )
    AND
    (
      (BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME)='Henry on the Hill'
    )
  )
ORDER BY
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME
```

After removing unneeded brackets it looks like below:

```
SELECT
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE,
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME,
  BOOK.TITLE,
  BOOK.TYPE,
  INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM,
  BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME
FROM
  PUBLISHER
  INNER JOIN BRANCH
  INNER JOIN BOOK
  INNER JOIN INVENTORY
             ON BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE
                AND
                BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM
                AND
                PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE = BOOK.PUBLISHER_CODE
WHERE
  BOOK.TYPE='FIC'
  AND
  (BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME = 'Henry on the Hill')
ORDER BY
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME
```

Looks better, but it's possible to avoid ordering problems just by transforming ANSI syntax to normal query:
**WARNING: ANSI syntax funs, please don't read rest of this answer :-)**

```
SELECT
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE,
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME,
  BOOK.TITLE,
  BOOK.TYPE,
  INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM,
  BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME
FROM
  PUBLISHER,
  BRANCH,
  BOOK,
  INVENTORY
WHERE
  BOOK.TYPE='FIC'
  AND
  (BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME = 'Henry on the Hill')
  AND
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE = BOOK.PUBLISHER_CODE
  AND
  BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE
  AND
  BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM
ORDER BY
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME
```

With this variant order of conditions doesn't matter and all conditions placed toghether, so it's possible to reorganize it in logical order:

```
SELECT
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE,
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME,
  BOOK.TITLE,
  BOOK.TYPE,
  INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM,
  BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME
FROM
  BRANCH,
  INVENTORY,
  BOOK,
  PUBLISHER
WHERE
  (BRANCH.BRANCH_NAME = 'Henry on the Hill') -- start from most restrictive 
                                             -- condition (concrete branch)  
  AND
  INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM = BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM   -- get all inventory from this branch
  AND
  BOOK.BOOK_CODE = INVENTORY.BOOK_CODE       -- access book specification 
                                             -- corresponding to inventory
  AND    
  BOOK.TYPE = 'FIC'                          -- of specific type 
  AND
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_CODE = BOOK.PUBLISHER_CODE  -- and finally find 
                                                  -- all publishers of that books
ORDER BY
  PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_NAME
```

So in a last variant it's possible to reproduce a query logic in human readable format.
Note, that order of tables in a query text (at least in Oracle  if you don't use some special hints) doesn't affect real query execution plan because optimizer changes it on it's own as needed. Therefore ANSI variant in most situations just introduces syntax restrictions without a real help.

Comment: Your statement *"Therefore ANSI variant in most situations just introduces syntax restrictions without a real help"* sounds like something you have proven, but you really haven't, as far as I can tell. IMO ANSI query syntax is far better in terms of readability and clarity, is more self-documenting (such as intended type of joins), and is better at preventing errors in joins (such as missing joins), which your approach would never catch. On top of that, I find your format harder to read and with redundant comments such as "corresponding to inventory" which are made quite clear in ANSI syntax.

Comment: @RedFilter Seems that you missing a warning at the middle of the answer :) It's different strokes for different folks. So *IMO* is a best qualification for both points of view.